# How to associate user to IPN

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, devise, paypal-ipn

I am using rails to create an app where a use can by coins useing paypal. I am using a generic buy now button created on the Paypal site. I have the button is set to give a IPN to a URL on my website. 
Previously I had issues with authenticating but useing the code below I have solved it. The issue now is that when the IPN notifies the controller but the session is destroyed so I have no way to give the use the coins. So my question is how can I retrieve/keep the session or user so that I can add the coins to the correct account?

**User Model (relevant parts):**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

# Gets the amount of coins the user currently has.
# @return The amount of coins the user has.
def get_coins
self.coins
end

# Adds an amount of coins to the user and saves to the database.
# @param amount The amount of coins to add to the user.
def add_coins(amount)
full_amount = amount + self.coins
self.coins = full_amount
self.save
end
```

**Controller the IPN points to:**

```
class PaymentNotificationsController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:create]
# POST /payment_notifications
# POST /payment_notifications.json

def create
puts "made it here"
#PaymentNotification.create!(:params => params)
user =User.find(session[:user_id])
user.coins += 100
user.save!
render :nothing => true
end
end
```

currently the above code has an error saying "cant find user with id="

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_action :authenticate_user!
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
end
```

Comment: hey again. Please post the model code for your User and IPN.

Comment: I don't have code for IPN. As for the User, can do.

Comment: To clarify I didn't code the IPN, Im only using the paypal "defualt" one that I set up in my facilitator account profile. To my knowledge it has set parameters that i do not know how to changes. As for the User, code added. Also thanks for the help still.

Comment: what model/table etc is being affected by the call PayPal is making?

Comment: You see it all in the code above. Paypal calls the URL that corresponds to the PaymentNotificationsController. The User Im trying to get to in that model is a underlined table that has a integer called coins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPN is sent from the PayPal server to your server separate from the user session.  It would be its own session, so that's why you're not getting any session data.  It's not getting destroyed.  It's just an entirely different session.

If you want to pass the user ID so that it comes back in IPN you can use the "custom" parameter in your button code.  It's actually called "custom" and you can send whatever you want in it up to 256 characters.

So add the following to your button code...

`<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="{user_id_value}" />`

Then it will come back in IPN as `$_POST['custom']`.

Another way you could handle it (which is what I would recommend) is you could create your invoice record in your system, which would then have a related customer record, prior to sending the user to PayPal.  Then you can use the "invoice" parameter to pass your invoice ID to PayPal.  This way it'll be included with the PayPal transaction details and just provides a nice reference in the PayPal details.

Once again, that would come back in IPN as `$_POST['invoice']`, so you could then hit your database to pull any invoice or related customer details you need so that you can use it within your IPN script.

Comment: Thank you for the response it makes a lot of sense. Trying it now